# Liquidsoap play news once every hour

Tags: liquidsoap

I have an internet radio playing a playlist. 
The stream is managed by Liquidsoap. How can I make it play once news in every hour?

If I set a 0m0s-4m0s interval in switch and the track playing before the news finishes at x o'clock 1 minute and the news is 2 minutes long then it plays twice because the end of the news is still in the 0m0s-4m0s interval. I have tried the add function, but it resulted in playing both the news and music in the same time. If I just specify the start time rather than an interval then news is not going to be played if a track is still playing at the start time. I've also tried to put news into a playlist.once source and it worked, but it did not play next time.

Thanks for help in advance and sorry for my bad english. 
I post the current code below:

```
news = playlist.once("/professzor/dj/playlists/newsplist.m3u")
radio = fallback([switch([({0m0s-4m0s},news)]), pl, single("/professzor/dj/beep.wav")])
```